# What is wrong with this database design?

Tags: database

I was pointed out by someone else that the following database design have serious issues, can anyone tell me why?

1. a tb_user table saves all the users information
2. tb_user table will have 3 - 8 users only.
3. each user's data will be saved in a separate table, naming after the user's name.
   Say a user is called: bill_admin, then he has a seperate table, i.e. bill_admin_data, to save all data belongs to him. All users' data shared the same structure.

The person who pointed out this problem said I should merge all the data into one table, and uses FK to distinguish them, but I have the following statement:

1. users will only be 3 - 8, so there's not gonna be a lot of tables anyway.
2. each user has a very large data table, say 500K records.

Is it a bad practise to design database like this? And why? Thank you.

Comment: Ugh! The person who pointed that out is doing you a big favor. That is a HORRIBLE design. Can you edit your question to include the actual table design? It would make it easier to offer suggestions, examples of why this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it isn't very maintainable.

1) Adding data to a database should never require modifying the structure. In your model, if you ever need to add another person you will need a new table (or two). You may not think you will ever need to do this, but trust me. You will.

So assume, for example, you want to add functionality to your application to add a new user to the database. With this structure you will have to give your end users rights to create new tables, which creates security problems.

2) It violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). That is, you are creating multiple copies of the same table structure that are identical. This makes maintenance a pain in the butt.

3) Querying across multiple users will be unnecessarily complicated. There is no good reason to split each user into a separate table other than having a vendetta against the person who has to write queries against this DB model.

4) If you are splitting it into multiple tables for performance because each user has a lot of rows, you are reinventing the wheel. The RDBMS you are using undoubtedly has an indexing feature which allows it to efficiently query large tables. Your home-grown hack is not going to outperform the platform's approach for handling large data.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say it's bad design per se. It is just not the type of design for which relational databases are designed and optimized for.

Of course, you can store your data as you mention, but many operations won't be trivial. For example:

- Adding a new person
- Removing a person
- Generating reports based on data across all your people

If you don't really care about doing this. Go ahead and do your tables as you propose, although I would recommend using a non relational database, such as MongoDB, which is more suited for this type of structure.

If you prefer using relational databases, by aggregating data by type, and not by person gives you lots of flexibility when adding new people and calculating reports.

500k lines is not "very large", so don't worry about size when making your design.

Answer (score -1):

it is good to use Document based database like mongoDB  for these type of requirement.

Comment: That isn't really relevant to what is being asked. Arguably it isn't true either.